# Is there way to make sure some task finish before user put the app on sleep or terminate the app in Xamarin Forms on Android and iOS?

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.forms

I am trying to make the UX as smooth as possible by not letting user to wait for the delay for each of the HTTP request finish with server.

I want to stack-up all these tasks and run them in background while user stay in the app, finish them before the app completely goes the sleep mode or terminate the app.

I looked up Android do have Job Scheduler, but it seems platform specified and not available in Xamarin Forms and iOS.

The only solution I am currently thinking is to save each http request task into some json and execute them when user start up the app.

I am not so familiar with Android/iOS development, I am not sure if there is any limitation doing in such way.

Is there any way to do so with some library or service natively?

Comment: just run update remote data in async mode, this won't affect your ui. you dont have to bind it to sleep or finish.

Comment: I don't think it's a good way to stack-up all these tasks and run them in background while user stay in the app. If you have lots of tasks and it will make your app in a mess. Make your  HTTP request synchronously and it won't take too many time to load data.

Comment: @NickKovalsky This wouldn't allow me to let them retry to send the request if the user lost internet connection.  If it fail, I need to retry calling the http request and guarantee the http request is complete.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT The operation is related to User want to add/remove something, it is not critical either the add/remove is success due to business logic, so I don't really care if is success or not.  I just want to make the user feels there is no delay on anything.  i.e. Gmail app you don't need to wait until the delete operation complete.  You can even delete it offline.